# 404 after migration to development environment for multistore

Tags: multistore, development, 404-page

I recently copied over my files from my production environment over to a new development directory.

Production:
`/xtacolle/public_html/`

Development:
`/devxta/public_html/`

I also made a copy of the DB and changed it in:
`/devxta/public_html/app/etc/local.xml`

Lastly I updated my htaccess to the following and commented out the second site since it is not important for this environment:

```
## Magento Store Configuration

SetEnvIf Host dev\.xtacollectibles\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=xtacollectibles_com
SetEnvIf Host dev\.xtacollectibles\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^xtacollectibles\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=xtacollectibles_com
SetEnvIf Host ^xtacollectibles\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

When i try to visit the development site dev.xtacollectibles.com I am getting these two errors in the log:

`2016-12-28T21:05:37+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in /home/devdta/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 634 and defined  in /home/devdta/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php on line 395`

`2016-12-28T21:05:37+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in /home/devdta/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 654 and defined  in /home/devdta/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store/Group.php on line 275`

Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was missing some data in a few tables. I found people with similar issues and I used the the snippet below as a reference for knowing which tables to check

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```